# ES 6 Classes - Mixins

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mixins, traits

I'm coming up with View (HTML markup) and Utility (JavaScript - behavior) architecture and creating atomic classes for composing views and utilities using ES6 Class. There will be a need that multiple utility classes can be composed/mixed into a single view class.

How can ES6 Class API provide a way to mix-in class(es) into another/main class.  I've looked at `Object.assign` but that is for objects and not at class-level.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript classes right now and hopefully also in future
only can be extended from each other but can not be mixed
into one another. If at all, then most probably ***Lightweight Traits***
do make it into the specification one day.

Its architectural approach is specific to JavaScript. It
has been mentioned quite often in the last few years ...
esdiscuss.org: [»about lightweight traits«](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/about-lightweight-traits),
github.com/WebReflection: [»features :: with«](https://github.com/WebReflection/es-class/blob/master/FEATURES.md#with),
webreflection.blogspot.com: [»A future friendly, backward compatible, class utility«](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2015/02/a-future-friendly-backward-compatible.html),
reddit.com/r/javascript: [»Functional Mixins in ECMAScript 2015«](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3a7hxz/functional_mixins_in_ecmascript_2015/),
raganwald.com: [»Functional Mixins in ECMAScript 2015«](http://raganwald.com/2015/06/17/functional-mixins.html) ...
and possibly is best compared to Angus Croll's [*Flight Mixins*](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/).

Pure function based Mixin/Trait approaches ... [This is not an essay about 'Traits in Javascript'](http://raganwald.com/2015/12/31/this-is-not-an-essay-about-traits-in-javascript.html),
[The many »Talents« of JavaScript](http://peterseliger.blogspot.de/2014/04/the-many-talents-of-javascript.html#the-many-talents-of-javascript) ...
do come closest to what the OP has ask for unless something
similar to ...

```
//  proposed trait syntax ...       //  ... desugared e.g. to ...

trait Enumerable_first_last {       //  var Enumerable_first_last = (function () {
  // trait body.                    //    // mixin module.
                                    //
  const                             //    var
    FIRST = function () {           //      first = function () { // shared code.
      return this[0];               //        return this[0];
    },                              //      },
    LAST = function () {            //      last = function () {
      return this[this.length - 1]; //        return this[this.length - 1];
    }                               //      }
  ;                                 //    ;
                                    //
  applicator () {                   //    return function Enumerable_first_last () {
    // applicator body.             //      // mixin body.
                                    //
    this.first = FIRST;             //      this.first = first; // referencing ...
    this.last = LAST;               //      this.last = last;   // ...  shared code.
  }                                 //    };
                                    //
}                                   //  }());
```

...

```
//  proposed trait syntax ...       //  ... desugared e.g. to ...

trait Enumerable_item {             //  var Enumerable_item = (function () {
                                    //
  const                             //    var
    ITEM = function (idx) {         //      item = function (idx) {
      return this[                  //        return this[
        Math.floor(                 //          Math.floor(
          parseFloat(idx, 10)       //            parseFloat(idx, 10)
        )                           //          )
      ];                            //        ];
    }                               //      }
  ;                                 //    ;
                                    //
  applicator () {                   //    return function Enumerable_item () {
                                    //
    this.item = ITEM;               //      this.item = item;
  }                                 //    };
                                    //
}                                   //  }());
```

...

```
//  proposed trait syntax ...       // ... desugared e.g. to ...

trait Enumerable_first_last_item {  //  var Enumerable_first_last_item = (function () {
                                    //
  use Enumerable_first_last;        //    return function Enumerable_first_last_item() {
  use Enumerable_item;              //
/*                                  //      Enumerable_first_last.call(this);
  applicator () {                   //      Enumerable_item.call(this);
    // can be omitted if empty.     //    };
  }*/                               //
}                                   //  }());
```

...

```
                                      //  ... desugared e.g. to ...
                                      //
class Queue {                         //  var Queue = (function () {
                                      //
//use Allocable;                      //    return function Queue () {
  use Observable;                     //      var list = [];
                                      //
  constructor () {                    //      this.enqueue = function (type) {
    const list = [];                  //
                                      //        list.push(type);
    this.enqueue = function (type) {  //        return type;
                                      //      };
      list.push(type);                //      this.dequeue = function () {
      return type;                    //
    };                                //        return list.shift();
    this.dequeue = function () {      //      };
                                      //
      return list.shift();            //    //Allocable.call(this, ...);
    };                                //      Observable.call(this);
  }                                   //    };
                                      //
}                                     //  }());
                                      //
var q = new Queue;                    //  var q = new Queue;
                                      //
q.enqueue(9);                         //  q.enqueue(9);
q.enqueue(8);                         //  q.enqueue(8);
q.enqueue(7);                         //  q.enqueue(7);
                                      //
console.log(q.dequeue());             //  console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());             //  console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());             //  console.log(q.dequeue());
                                      //
console.log(q);                       //  console.log(q);
console.log(Object.keys(q));          //  console.log(Object.keys(q));
```

... was shipped to ECMAScript land.

Comment: 1/2 - In order to prove the above sketched trait syntax I provided a lib and exemplarily did refactor the code of 4 other Trait related JavaScript Qs too, which ara (1)[Compostions and mixins in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999608/compostions-and-mixins-in-js/43141778#43141778), (2)[Mixins for ES6 classes, transpiled with babel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732241/mixins-for-es6-classes-transpiled-with-babel/43129978#43129978), ...

Comment: 2/2 - (3)[Refactoring legacy mixin-based class hierarchies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027388/refactoring-legacy-mixin-based-class-hierarchies/43059101#43059101) and (4)[Multiple inheritance using classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918874/multiple-inheritance-using-classes/43748183#43748183).

Answer (score 1):

There is a really nice pattern with ES2015 classes (which I don't necessarily endorse as such) to create mixins [by Sebastian Markbage](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fac0830dbb13ccbff596), which I've slightly adapted.

The utility function `mixinClasses` can be used to mix in class factories (aka factory functions that return classes) into your new class:

```
function mixinClasses(...mixins) {
  // TODO: Add all possible method names that might call super()
  // to the base class so that they don't throw.
  return mixins.reduce((base, mixin) => {
      return mixin(base);
  }, class {});
}
```

Which can be used as follows, for example with the two factory functions `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
const Foo = base => class extends base {
  myFn() {
  }
};

const Bar = base => class extends base {
  myFn() {
    super.myFn();
  }
};

class Baz extends mixinClasses(Foo, Bar) {
  myFn() {
    super.myFn();
  }
}
```