# Flux Stores: Why extend EventEmitter.prototype?

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, flux, eventemitter

Every offical Flux example I can find uses this pattern for creating a store:

```
var MyStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  ...
});
```

I don't understand why we're assigning methods directly on the `MyStore` object when we could just inherit those methods by making `MyStore` an instance of `EventEmitter`:

```
var MyStore = assign(new EventEmitter(), {
  ...
});
```

Does anyone know the rationale behind this pattern? especially since it is commonly misread, causing bugs like this:

```
var MyStore = assign(EventEmitter.prototype, {
  ...
});
```

If I were to venture a guess, I would say it's because they don't want to invoke the EventEmitter constructor and they want you to easily chain more prototypes, like so:

```
var MyStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, A.prototype,
                     B.prototype, C.prototype, randomObject, {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is a bias to favoring composition over inheritance in Javascript. I suppose you may find people to argue the case for inheritance, however, setting aside any of the arguments about which is conceptually superior, one certain advantage composition over inheritance offers in JS is that it lets one trivially simulate multiple inheritance (which is not otherwise possible in JS).

Before `Object.assign()` was making its way into ES6, libraries like jQuery, underscore/lodash, and prototype  had similar functions named `extend()` (which lodash at least now aliases to its `assign` function). In my opinion the `extend` name is an easier clue to how/why it is being used, but it's just a name. I think some libraries also have functions named "mixin" - same deal, and the use of composition sometimes gets referred to as using "mixins."

This SO question (and its top answer) may be of interest [Composition, Inheritance, and Aggregation in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696695/composition-inheritance-and-aggregation-in-javascript)

Like a lot of Javascript idioms, it might take some getting used to, especially if you have a classical OO background. But embrace the idiom and you'll get used to more easily spotting the sort of error you mention at the end of your question, the same way one gets used to dealing with closures, asynchronous code, and all the other things that make Javascript wild and wonderful.

Comment: `assign()`/`extend()` isn't *technically* doing composition or inheritance, though it's roughly analogous to multiple inheritance. I don't see true composition in JavaScript that often, but I see this pattern all the time.

Comment: @wolverdude - So in my answer, I said that it allows the simulation of multiple inheritance. I didn't say it was multiple inheritance. Please let me know if I failed to answer your question.

Comment: @wolverdude - also, please clarify what you mean by "true composition" and an example of "true composition" in Javascript (since you said you don't often see it, it is implied that you do occasionally see it).