# Passing variables using object composition in javascript

Tags: javascript, composition, object-composition

I've been trying to wrap my head around Object Composition for a while and I can't seem to find the "correct way" to do the same I was doing before with OOP. Lets say I have a class Entity with 3 variables, with OOP I would just create a class Entity and all the children of this class would have these 3 properties, but using object composition I can't seem to understand how I'm supposed to mimic this inheritance.

```
const Entity = {
    let self = {
         x: 0,
         y: 0,
         z: 0,
}
```

Do I need to create these properties in all other objects I create that need them? Or is there a better way to reuse these properties?

```
const ObjectX = {
     let state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        abc: 0,
        cba: 0,
return Object.assign(state, canDoX);
}

const ObjectY = {
     let state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        foo: 0,
        bar: 0,
return Object.assign(state, canDoY);
}
```

Comment: Object literals should not have a return value or a comma at the end of the property list.

Comment: Code that you are showing us won't even compile `const Entity = {}` is literal object declaration and what should follow are key/value pairs, but you have some `let self` statement there which is definitely incorrect and will automatically throw an error.

Comment: `Entity and all the children of this class would have these 3 properties`, in Javascript you would use the protototype, but first you need to create a Class, not an Object..

Comment: @Keith creating a class is cool, but it is just syntactic sugar, so I would not say you **need** to create one, but perhaps you **should** create one. I think it's important to understand how the underlying functions and objects work in javascript in order to understand how a Class works in javascript.

Comment: @MatusDubrava I've been following this [guide](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6) so I assumed it was the way to do it.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Well first things first, this isn't object composition. It looks like your guide may have learned from MPJ's videos, but MPJ got composition completely, entirely wrong. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I just posted a reply to your guide with more detailed information. https://medium.com/@jeffm712/youve-been-misinformed-a96c0d1fb4fe

Comment: @JeffM I will take a look at it, thank you for your contribution. Do you perhaps known of a trustable source for learning Object Composition?

Comment: The first and easiest is wikipedia. Composition\_over\_inheritance and Has-a articles describe composition as containing instances and as having a member field of an object. The Python community, the ActionScript community (ActionScript is an ECMAScript language), the C++ community, JavaScript-specific explanations that pre-date the recent spread of misinformation, and most importantly the GoF book -- where the rule favor composition over inheritance comes from -- all describe composition that same way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a - https://web.archive.org/web/20170707220607/https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html - http://www.artima.com/cppsource/codestandards3.html - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696786/1698612 - https://i.imgur.com/xDHUGYc.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend (via prototype) some object with another object then you can use `Object.create` method which takes an object as argument and creates a new object with this passed in object linked to it via prototype chain.

```js
const entity = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
};

const objectX = Object.create(entity);
objectX.abc = 'something';

console.log(objectX.x);
console.log(objectX.y);
console.log(objectX.z);
console.log(objectX.abc);
```

If you just want to mix one object into another then you can use `Object.assign` and pass an empty object as the first argument and the `entity` object as the second argument to this method which will then create a new object with all the properties copied from the `entity` (note that this is only a shallow copy therefore you need to take some special care if that `entity` contains some other objects inside of it - those will be copied by reference therefore you would mutate the original ones if you would update them).

```js
const entity = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    z: 3
};

const objectX = Object.assign({}, entity);
objectX.abc = 'something';

console.log(objectX.x);
console.log(objectX.y);
console.log(objectX.z);
console.log(objectX.abc);
```

Last thing, `Object.assign` can be replaced by object destructuring like this.

```
const objectX = { ...entity };
```

But again, this also produces only a shallow copy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is definitely what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a constructor?

```js
function BatLoser(batterName){
  this.batter = batterName; this.balls = 0; this.strikes = 0; this.onBase = false; this.strikeOut = false;
  this.swing = function(){
    var zeroOneTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    switch(zeroOneTwo){
      case 0:
        this.balls++;
        console.log('ball '+this.balls+' for '+this.batter);
        break;
      case 1:
        this.strikes++;
        console.log('strike '+this.strikes+' for '+this.batter);
        break;
      case 2:
        this.onBase = true;
        console.log(this.batter+' hits the ball and is on base');
        return this;
    }
    if(this.balls > 3){
      this.onBase = true;
      console.log(this.batter+' walks on base');
    }
    if(this.strikes > 2){
      this.strikeOut = true;
      console.log(this.batter+' struck out');
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.batterUp = function(){
    while(!this.onBase && !this.strikeOut){
      this.swing();
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var bob = new BatLoser('Bob'), joe = new BatLoser('Joe');
bob.batterUp(); console.log('-------'); joe.batterUp();
```

Just keep hitting that button to see how the results vary.

Note that every `new` instance of a Constructor creates a `new` Object. Object literals do not have a `__constructor` method, or whatever you are used to.